# Width of Gaussian Beam and Refractive Index

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, waves, refraction

I know that in free space, the width of a Gaussian beam can be written as $W=W_0\sqrt{1+(\frac{z}{z_0})^{2}}$. However, I was wondering if it was possible to express this width as a function of refractive index instead (since I don't believe a Gaussian beam originating in say, glass, will diverge in the same manner as one in air). Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and the formula you already have still works. Take *z* to be the optical path length: refractive index *n* times physical distance. A Gaussian beam in glass diverges in exactly the same way as in free space, only 'squeezed' in the *z* direction by a factor of *n*.

Comment: Looks good. Could you take a look at my other question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38730/transmission-of-gaussian-beam-through-graded-index-slab, which is related to this one?